# unable to connect on citrix workspace on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, certificates, citrix

i am not finding the step-8 in Firefox and whenever i am opening ica file , its not redirecting to citrix site just opening in the terminal.

I have tried all the steps-

**step-1**
http://mark911.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/how-to-install-citrix-receiver-icaclient-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit-tested-and-working-using-mozilla-firefox/

**step-2**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

**step-3**
Go to https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/legacy-receiver-for-linux/receiver-for-linux-13-2.html

Look for "File Type: .deb" under the Download buttons.

**step-4**

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/icaclient_*.deb ctxusb_*.deb
sudo apt-get -f install 
# Install dependencies and finish configuring the package(s)
```

**step-5(added ssl certificates)**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
```

**step-6(Configure Citrix Receiver)**
Run:

```
/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/configmgr &
```

**step-7**(64-bit only) Fix Firefox plugin installation

Run:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npwrapper.npica.so /usr/lib/firefox/plugins/npwrapper.npica.so
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npica.so
sudo ln -s /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/npica.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npica.so
sudo ln -s /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/npica.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/npica.so
```

**step-8(Configure Firefox)**

In Firefox, go to Tools -> Add-ons -> Plugins, and make sure the "Citrix Receiver for Linux" plugin is set to "Always Activate".

After following with the above process I am unable to find citrix inside my firefox plugin section.

I have also referenced citrix help documents to trust ca-certificates but still I am unable to use Citrix Workspace/Receiver
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX231524/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux-how-to-trust-a-ca-certificate

[image: citrix error]

Comment: I am facing the similar issue...

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 22.04 the most recent working version is "Citrix Workspace app 2207 for Linux GA"

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/legacy-workspace-app-for-linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest-OLD1.html

Use the download above x86_64 and follow the instructions for Debian here:

https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/install.html